# Cannot get flutter running in Docker

Tags: docker, flutter, ubuntu-18.04, chmod

My Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Project files
ARG PROJECT_DIR=/srv/api
RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_DIR

WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR


# Update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y xz-utils
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_v1.7.8+hotfix.4-stable.tar.xz -o /flutter.tar.xz
RUN tar xf /flutter.tar.xz 
#RUN mv flutter /srv/api/flutter
RUN ls /srv/api/flutter
RUN chmod a+x /srv/api/flutter
RUN flutter doctor

# Install Flutter dependencies
RUN flutter upgrade
RUN flutter packages pub global activate webdev
RUN flutter packages upgrade


# Copy everything to Docker
COPY ./ ./
```

Fails at `RUN flutter doctor`

If I put in path `/srv/api/flutter` I receive error `flutter: not found`.
If I put in path `/usr/local/bin/flutter` I receive error `flutter: Permission Denied`.

I tried putting it in regular directory and in /usr directory. Both ways have failed. I tried searching about it but nothing seems to be working.

How can I fix it?

Comment: The `flutter: Permission Denied` error is related to trying to execute a directory, the command is available in the `./bin/` directory of the `flutter_linux_v1.7.8+hotfix.4-stable.tar.xz` package (e.g. would be `/usr/local/bin/flutter/bin/flutter`).

Comment: Hey @masseyb, that's not correct. After tar'ing ```Flutter.tar.xz``` it will have flutter folder. Within ```flutter``` folder there will be ```/bin``` directory where flutter resides. I'm checking every step with ```ls``` in Docker, as common practice of myself to not mess up haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flutter` is available in the `./bin/` directory of the `flutter` package. Slightly modified `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG PROJECT_DIR=/srv/api
ENV PATH=/opt/flutter/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        xz-utils \
        git \
        openssh-client \
        curl && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apt

RUN curl -L https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_v1.7.8+hotfix.4-stable.tar.xz | tar -C /opt -xJ

WORKDIR ${PROJECT_DIR}
COPY ./ ./

RUN flutter doctor
RUN flutter upgrade
RUN flutter packages pub global activate webdev
RUN flutter packages upgrade
```

This example extracts the `flutter` package to `/opt` and sets `/opt/flutter/bin` in the `$PATH` - the `flutter` executable is at `/opt/flutter/bin/flutter`.

**Note**:

- `WORKDIR` creates the directory if it doesn't already exist -
  removing the `RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_DIR` removes a layer from the
  final image ([`RUN`, `COPY` and `ADD` create layers](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers)).
- Combined the `apt-get update && apt-get install -y ...` and removed the `apt-get upgrade` for reasons stated in
  the
  [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run).
- Split the packages to install on multiple lines because it's easier to 
  see what changes in a `diff` imo.
- Combined the `curl | tar`.
- Removed the `ls /srv/api/flutter` and `chmod a+x /srv/api/flutter` 
  `RUN`'s.

Comment: Copy-Pasted - it worked! 
Could you please explain more about your code? As I'd love to learn more about docker's initialization too. 
For example, why we need to provide ```ENV PATH```, why opt is so special (I saw many people with flutter using this path), why ```WORKDIR``` initialized in the end vs in the beginning?

Comment: @zeromaro `/opt` [is reserved for all the software and add-on packages that are not part of the default installation.](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/opt.html) The `ENV` is to set the `$PATH` where `bash` will look for the command ([1.4.1.7. Executing commands](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html)). The `WORKDIR` setting is by preference, I set it if / when I need it, it makes it clearer for me to see what's going on.

Comment: Great comment, really appreciate your efforts! Thanks alot